# Matplotlib Embed a graph in to a UI PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a function in another script that draws a graph, so the graph is already predrawn, I just want to place it in to a widget on my interface in PyQt5. I have imported it, and when it runs it opens two windows, one with the graph in and one with the user interface in. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
def minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg):
    x = recentMinionRatioAvg
    a = x*10
    b = 100-a
    sizes = [a, b]
    colors = ['#0047ab', 'lightcoral']
    plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors)

    #determine score colour as scolour
    if x < 5:
       scolour = "#ff6961" #red
    elif 5 <= x < 5.5:
       scolour = "#ffb347" #orange
    elif 5.5 <= x < 6.5:
       scolour = "#77dd77" #light green
    elif 6.5 <= x:
       scolour = "#03c03c" # dark green

    #draw a circle at the center of pie to make it look like a donut
    centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.75, fc=scolour,linewidth=1.25)
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

    # Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

This is in one script. In my GUI script, I have imported these:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as 
FigureCanvas
from graphSetup import *
```

And at the start of my window class, before the setup function, I have this function:

```
def minionGraphSetup(self, recentMinionRatioAvg):
    minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `plt.show` you need to place the figure that is produced by your imported script into the FigureCanvas of your PyQt GUI.

So in your plotting script do

```
def minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg):
    ...
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    plt.axis('equal')
    #plt.show() <- don't show window!
    return fig
```

In your GUI script use the figure obtained to place it into the canvas.

```
def minionGraphSetup(self, recentMinionRatioAvg):
    fig = minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg)
    ...
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig, ...)
```

---

If you want to return an image, you can save it to a Byte buffer,

```
import io
def minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg):
    ...
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    plt.axis('equal')
    buff = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buff, format="png")
    return buff
```

and then show it as image in the PyQt GUI. (I haven't tested the below, so it may work a bit differently.)

```
def minionGraphSetup(self, recentMinionRatioAvg):
    image = minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg)
    label = QLabel() 
    pixmap = QPixmap(image)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: while this works, It wasn't what I was looking for, not your fault, mine. Do you know how I could maybe export the graph as just an image straight to the gui? I know you can save the graph as an image, but how could you put the updated image on the screen, as far as I'm aware, when you compile a resource file, all the images stay the same, I don't know how to reload it.

Comment: I updated the answer for an image. I cannot test it currently, so take it more as a roadmap than working code.

Comment: The code stops working at `pixmap = QPixmap(image)` and I'm unsure why? Any thoughts? Also, how would I place that in to my window? Would I pass in the name of the window and put self.centralwidget in to the QLabel parentheses? Thanks